# java 8 lambda expression for FilenameFilter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am going through the lambda expression in java 8

when i changed the code of thread it's working fine

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run");
    }
}).start();
```

is converted to lambda expression as

```
new Thread(
    () -> System.out.println("Hello from thread")
).start();
```

But i am not able to convert the FilenameFilter Expression

```
File file = new File("/home/text/xyz.txt");
file.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        name.endsWith(".txt");
        return false;
    }
});
```

and unsuccessfully converted to this as

```
file.list(new FilenameFilter () {
    (File a1, String a2) -> { 
        return false;
    }
});
```

it's giving error as in eclipse as

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
>     - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
>     - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete       Assignment

Comment: Why use `File` if you use Java 8? Why not java.nio.file?

Comment: You should accept an answer, to aknowledge that the issue is solved...

Comment: @fge i will use it from now

Comment: As this comes up up on Google a lot, heres a one liner in Java 8: `Files.list(Paths.get("your/path")).filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First things first, your formatting is **horrible**, sort it out!

Now, lambda syntax; to convert the anonymous class:

```
final FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

We start by replacing the anonymous class with an equivalent lambda for the single method `accept(File dir, String name)`:

```
final FilenameFilter filter = (File dir, String name) -> {
    return false;
};
```

But we can do better, we don't need to define the types - the compiler can work those out:

```
final FilenameFilter filter = (dir, name) -> {
    return false;
};
```

And we can do better still, as the method return a `boolean`; if we have a single statement that evaluates to a `boolean` we can skip the `return` and the braces:

```
final FilenameFilter filter = (dir, name) -> false;
```

This can be any statement, for example:

```
final FilenameFilter filter = (dir, name) -> !dir.isDirectory() && name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
```

However, the `File` API is **very** old, so don't use it. Use the [`nio API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html). This has been around since Java 7 in 2011 so there is really **no** excuse:

```
final Path p = Paths.get("/", "home", "text", "xyz.txt");
final DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> f = path -> false;
try (final DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(p, f)) {
    stream.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

And in fact your example has a specific method built into `Files` that [takes a Glob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-):

```
final Path p = Paths.get("/", "home", "text", "xyz.txt");
try (final DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(p, "*.txt")) {
    stream.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Or, using the more modern [`Files.list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
final Path p = Paths.get("/", "home", "text", "xyz.txt");
final PathMatcher filter = p.getFileSystem().getPathMatcher("glob:*.txt");
try (final Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(p)) {
    stream.filter(filter::matches)
          .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Here `filter::matches` is a method reference because the method `PathMatcher.matches` can be used to implement the functional interface `Predicate<Path>` as it takes a `Path` and returns a `boolean`.

---

As an aside:

```
f.list(new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        name.endsWith(".txt");
        return false;
    }
});
```

This makes no sense...

Comment: Any reasoning behind not using the `File` API just because it's old?

Comment: @citizenconn first and foremost; the `File` API has abysmal error reporting, most methods return a `boolean`, leaving it up to you to work out why an operation failed. Other issues are lack of features, the NIO API has a huge number of utility functions for almost anything. Finally, actually _reading_ from files using the old API is verbose and errorprone - NIO greatly simplifies the whole process, for example the default charset is UTF-8 rather than whatever your current platform decides. And that's just for starters...

Comment: nio APIs are not working in Android 7 OS, I am getting error

Comment: Unfortunately the `Stream` variants are not very practical when the operation per file could throw `IOException` due to lack of checked exception support in common functional interfaces.

Answer (score 9):

`FileNameFilter` is a functional interface. You don't need to instantiate it explicitly.

```
    f.list((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".txt"));
```

Note also, that `f` should be a directory, not a file as in your example. Your example where `f1` is a file will return `null` with the specified filter.

Comment: Exactly the one line solution that I was looking for when I found the "java 8 lambda expression for FilenameFilter" page. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

It should be simpler :

```
f.list((File a1, String a2) -> {return false;});
```

or even :

```
f.list((a1,a2) -> {return false;});
```

The lambda expression replaces the instantiation of the abstract class instance.

Comment: Or even `(file, n) -> false`. There's no reason to use a block.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put the class name, if you use a lambda-expression:

```
 f.list(
    (File a1, String a2) -> { 
        return false; }
    );
```

In fact, in your first example, you omit `new Runnable()`.

Comment: This formatting is equally horrible, and the answer is _almost_ wrong.