# Deleting files for android espresso test

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have a MainMenu activity that gets data from file and displays it. I want the data to be deleted at the start of each espresso test and to not persist between tests.

I have tried the following:

```
Context mContext;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
    File[] files = mContext.getFilesDir().listFiles();
    if(files != null){
        for(File file : files) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it is not deleting the files. I believe the context might not be correct. Is there a way to clear internal storage at the start of an espresso test?

The files are '.ser' files.

Comment: Are you trying to delete files from the app's "files" folder or from the test app "files" folder?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using adb shell commands?

One thing I tried that was helpful in deleting files in an Espresso test was executing ADB shell commands programmatically.  Something like this:

(Kotlin sample)

```
val dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    val file = File(dir.absolutePath
            + File.separator + directoryInExtStorageDir
            + File.separator + fileName)
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
            "rm -f " + file.absolutePath)
```

Java would look something like this:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator + directoryInExtStorageDir
            + File.separator + fileName)
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
            "rm -f " + file.getAbsolutePath())
```

As for seeking out files of a specific type you can use the FilenameFilter  or FileFilter interfaces for that.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29316439/2328196) and [this page](https://www.boraji.com/java-8-filefilter-example-using-lambda-expression) for examples of how you can do this.

An example might look like this:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File directory = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator + directoryInExtStorageDir);
    List<File> filesToDelete = Arrays.asList(directory.listFiles((new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".ser");
        }
    })));

    filesToDelete.forEach(file->{
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                "rm -f " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    });
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. The solution was only to change getContext() for getTargetContext()

```
mContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
    File[] files = mContext.getFilesDir().listFiles();
    if(files != null){
        for(File file : files) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
```

As simple as that :)

Comment: Simple just until you find limitations.. Your activity is created first and then your setup is run so it can work for you , until it will not..

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin..

```
@BeforeClass
fun beforeClass() {
    getInstrumentation().targetContext.filesDir.deleteRecursively()
}

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class SomeTest {
    
    @Test
    fun someFreshInstallationTest() {
        ...
    }
    
}
```