# How to scan a specific directory for files with a specific extension?

Tags: java

Say I have a particular directory somewhere on my system.
`C://Users/Public/Local/AppData/saves`

I want to read this whole directory and check if the files in it have a particular extension or not. Say `.json` for example.
If the directory has multiple files with the extension `.json` list all those files with their names.

I could use 
`File file = new File(myPath);`
and do `file.exists()` continuously but how can I scan the whole directory for files?
Here is what I am confused with.

Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: May be this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189094/how-to-scan-a-folder-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old school very readable file name filter:

```
    File[] jsonFiles=new File("sourcePath").listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File arg0, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".json");
        }
    });
```

Or if you want to use lambda stuff:
see [java 8 lambda expression for FilenameFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316310/java-8-lambda-expression-for-filenamefilter)

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you can use `Files.walk`

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/path/to/folder/"))
.filter(p -> p.toString().endsWith(".json"))
.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getFileName()));
```